# .NET Runtime Error in Event Log, P fields

Tags: .net, windows, event-log

A service we have is occasionally crashing on a test PC.

We are getting some information in the Event Log, a ".NET Runtime 2.0 Error" with some details.

I've determined that P1 is the executable, P2 is the version, P5 is the .NET Runtime, but what are the rest of the fields (P1-P10)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

These details are Watson buckets, that are used to group crash reports that get sent back to Microsoft.  Some more details are in the MSDN article [Unhandled Exception Processing In The CLR](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc793966.aspx).  From that article:

> [T]he CLR will collect the managed
>   bucket details pertaining to the
>   unhandled exception and write them to
>   the event log (under the Application
>   Log)...
>
> Bucketing is the process that groups
>   crashes of applications based upon the
>   point of crash. In case of unhandled
>   managed exceptions, it is based upon
>   nine details that the CLR collects
>   pertaining to the managed exception
>   that went unhandled. These are
>   collectively known as the Watson
>   buckets, and in the context of managed
>   code they include details such as the
>   name of the module that was
>   responsible for the crash, the
>   intermediate language (IL) offset at
>   which the crash happened, and the
>   MethodDef of the method in which the
>   crash happened

Answer (score 0):

not exactly all you asked, but
maybe [this](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/913384) will help. look at the "Error message 2" title.
to get more data on the error , you might want to take a crash dump with AdPlus